# Can't see the inserted files in my database using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, fetch, bulkinsert, database-cursor

I have this code and executes with no issues but i dont see the tables or files that are supposed to be in the 'Names' Database [here is the queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmhCY.jpg)

[And this is the data im trying to insert in bulk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUteJ.jpg)

also here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE import_txt_files12
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @file varchar(255)
  DECLARE @path varchar(255)
  DECLARE @sql varchar(8000)
  DECLARE @tablename varchar(255)

  SET @path = 'C:\Users\marti\OneDrive\Desktop\Data Analist course\Datasets\names\'

  DECLARE file_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files
    WHERE [name] LIKE 'yob%' AND physical_name LIKE @path + '%'

  OPEN file_cursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM file_cursor INTO @file

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    -- Extract table name from file name
    SET @tablename = SUBSTRING(@file, LEN(@path), LEN(@file) - LEN(@path) - 4)

    SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT [Names].[dbo].[' + @tablename + '] FROM ''' + @file + ''' WITH (FORMAT = ''txt'', FIRSTROW = 1, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM file_cursor INTO @file
  END

  CLOSE file_cursor
  DEALLOCATE file_cursor
END
```

Comment: Take a look at the value you defined in `@Path` and compare that with the path in your Explorer screenshot. You will also need a `GO` between your stored procedure definition and the `EXEC` statement that calls it (visible in image only).

Comment: When I click the address bar in the explorer that's the address it automatically gives me to copy, just realized the screenshot shows in Spanish but when I click to copy it it goes to English, maybe that could be?
Also, the 'GO' is right before executing the PROCEDURE import_txt_files12? or inside the WHILE loop where executing @sql?

Thanks!!

Comment: A `GO` needs to be added after the last `END`, before the `exec`. However, another problem is that I'm pretty sure that `sys.master_files` is not going to list the contents of an arbitrary folder in Windows. Per the documentation, sys.master_files "contains a row per file of a database as stored in the master database". That would not include your files. If your SQL Server instance is running on your local machine, you might be able to use `xp_DirTree`. If your SQL Server instance is running on a different machine, you need to first move your files to a folder accessible to SQL Server.